# String memory issue: printing a string with printf seems to overwrite itself

Tags: c, string, malloc, trie

I am beginning to learn C using the MIT OCW intro course (the course can be found [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-087-practical-programming-in-c-january-iap-2010/index.htm)). I am going through one of the assignments in which you have to write functions to implement a trie structure as an English-to-French dictionary using the given template (found [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-087-practical-programming-in-c-january-iap-2010/assignments/assn06a.zip) in the file named prob2.c). Basically, the program is supposed to ask for a word to translate, look it up in the trie, and give the translation(s). I first attempted to implement it myself, but I kept running into an error where the result seemed to be printing "over" itself. Here is an example of what is happening since it is a little strange to explain:

```
Enter word to translate: Adam
,Adamo> Adam
Enter word to translate: word
,parole mot
Enter word to translate: hello
,eh oh-> salut
Enter word to translate: tree
tree -> arbre
```

For these inputs, it should look like this, so that the translations are delimited by only a comma:

```
Enter word to translate: Adam
Adam -> Adam,Adamo
Enter word to translate: word
word -> mot,parole
Enter word to translate: hello
hello -> salut,allo,eh oh
Enter word to translate: tree
tree -> arbre
```

After giving up and looking at the solution (found [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-087-practical-programming-in-c-january-iap-2010/assignments/MIT6_087IAP10_assn06a_sol.pdf), see Problem 6.2, the full problem description is included as well), my code was not very different from what was given. Regardless, I compiled again using the solution posted on OCW and there seems to be no change. I tried running the program with valgrind to see if there were any apparent memory issues that could explain this, but nothing came up while looking up words, just some issues with freeing the trie at the end.

Here is the function that I suspect could be the main issue (this is from the solution which I linked earlier in the post):

```
/* add word to trie, with translation
   input: word and translation
   output: non-zero if new node added, zero otherwise
   postcondition: word exists in trie */
int add_word(const char *word, char *translation) {
    struct s_trie_node *pnode = proot;
    int i, len = strlen(word), inew = 0;
    unsigned char j;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        j = word[i];
        if ((inew = !pnode->children[j]))
            pnode->children[j] = new_node();
        pnode = pnode->children[j];
    }
    if (pnode->translation) {
        /* concatenate strings */
        char *oldtranslation = pnode->translation;
        int oldlen = strlen(oldtranslation), newlen = strlen(translation);
        pnode->translation = malloc(oldlen + newlen + 2);
        strcpy(pnode->translation, oldtranslation);
        strcpy(pnode->translation + oldlen, ",");
        strcpy(pnode->translation + oldlen + 1, translation);
        free(oldtranslation);
    } else
        pnode->translation = strcpy(malloc(strlen(translation) + 1), translation);
    return inew;
}
```

If anybody can explain to me why this is happening and how to fix it, I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your translations are being entered with a CRLF ending, but the parsing code is looking for the LF terminator. Consequently, every translation has a CR on the end, just before the comma added by `add_word`. So, when you print them, the CR causes them to print one over another at the left edge of the screen.

Add a test in `add_word` to confirm this.

```
if (pnode->translation[oldlen-1] == '\r') ...
```

Comment: Ah, the joys of line-ending lunacy.

Comment: Tested it out and you were right. Just made a slight adjustment now to the load_dictionary() function to cut the carriage return if it follows the linefeed. Such a simple fix, totally thought the answer was going to be annoyingly complex. Thank you very much!